# Exception in AppDynamics JAVA Agent for Elasticsearch

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, appdynamics

I am trying to configure the AppDynamics Java agent for Elasticsearch 7.9.3 (Docker) version. The agent is registered in the AppDynamics but the agent status is showing down.

In AppDynamics logs I can see the below error.

03 Oct 2021 14:47:24,169  WARN JavaAgent - Exception caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/services/transactionmonitor/common/activity/CustomActivityUtil

03 Oct 2021 14:47:24,171  WARN JavaAgent - Exception caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/services/agentdiagnostics/safety/ErrorClassKey

03 Oct 2021 14:47:24,665  WARN JavaAgent - Exception caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/singularity/ee/agent/appagent/services/transactionmonitor/e2elatency/E2ELatencyUtil

I am unable to find a solution for this, looking for any suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: looks like this is a configuration problem check https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Java-Java-Agent-Installation-JVM/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-com-singularity-ee-agent-appagent/td-p/29468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your java.policy / default.policy files with the following grants

```
grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/appdynamics/java-agent/-", "read,write,execute,delete";
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "appdynamics.enable.field.injection", "read";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "appdynamics.agent.enablesop", "read";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.management.ManagementPermission "monitor";
};
```

**Edit to generalise advice based on comment from OP:**

More generally, logged errors can be translated into further additional permission config, e.g. For:

```
WARN BCIFixer - Error matching class [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction] [access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")]
```

Add:

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
```

Comment: Thanks Ingmar, after adding the above permissions in my security policy I can see no errors and agent is reporting. Thanks for the help.